# how to return two pipes from a function registered to a multiprocessing.manager?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have played around with this for a while and feel like I'm, constantly hitting my head against a wall i have 3 different bits of code the first two work and following logic the second one should as well.

This manager:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
def getAB(): return 'spam', 'eggs'
class MyManager(BaseManager): pass
MyManager.register('getAB', callable=getAB)
m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='A')
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

and this client:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
class MyManager(BaseManager): pass
MyManager.register('getAB')
manager = QueueManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey='A')
manager.connect()
a,b = manager.getAB()._getvalue()
print "a", a
print "b", b
```

work fine together and output

```
a spam
b eggs
```

by changing the getAB to this getPipe, and threading serve_forever you get these changes

```
pipeServer, pipeClient = Pipe()
def getPipe(): return pipeClient

t = Thread(target=s.serve_forever)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

print "pipe", pipeServer.recv()
```

and changing the end of the client to this

```
pipe = manager.getPipe()
pipe.send("spam")
```

gives

```
pipe spam
```

now putting both these together it would seem logical to assume you could have a function getPipes that returns two pipes this is my attempt:

```
pipe1Server, pipe1Client = Pipe()
pipe2Server, pipe2Client = Pipe()
def getPipes():
    return pipe1Client, pipe2Client

class MyManager(BaseManager): pass
MyManager.register('getPipes', callable=getPipes)
m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='A')
s = m.get_server()
t = Thread(target=s.serve_forever)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

print "1", pipe1Server.recv()
print "2", pipe2Server.recv()
```

and using this client you should be able to get the pipes and send to them

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
class MyManager(BaseManager): pass
MyManager.register('getPipes')
manager = MyManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey='A')
manager.connect()
data = manager.getPipes()
pipe1, pipe2 = data._getvalue()
pipe1.send("spam")
pipe2.send("eggs")
```

However i get this error: (in the client process)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 7, in <module>
    pipe1, pipe2 = data._getvalue()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 779, in _getvalue
    return self._callmethod('#GETVALUE')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 759, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
```

now i think this has something to do with the way the Connection objects are pickled but i have no idea how to get around this?